# Is it possible to show different divs on different areas of a Image Map?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am want to show different divs when one hovers over different areas on an Image Map. I tried creating a another `Map` tag but it didn't work.

Here's my code so far,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            #pipelines {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: auto;
                margin-bottom: auto;
                float: left;
            }
            #content {
                font-family: Helvetica Neue;
                color: #000;
                border: solid;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                background-color: white;
                position: relative;
                width: 20%;
                height: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding-bottom: 20%;
                display: none;
                float: left;
            }

            hr {
                background-color: #000;
            }

            #members {
                float: right;
                position: relative;
                font-family: Helvetica Neue;
                color: #000;
                border: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                width: 20%;
                text-align: center;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }

        </style>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Pipeline</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pipelines">
            <img src="2D_Pipeline.jpg" usemap="#Map" border="0"/>
            <map name="Map" id="Map">
              <area shape="rect" coords="29,77,143,105" href="#" alt="Writers" />
              <area shape="rect" coords="199,77,312,105" href="#" alt="Design"  />
            </map>

        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h4></h4>
            <hr />
            John Howard
            johnhoward@abc.com
            <br />
            (123) 456 - 7890
            <br />
            <button type="button" id="john">
                Add
            </button>
            <hr />
            Leslie Holmes
            lesliehomes@abc.com
            <br />
            (133) 336 - 7890
            <br />
            <button type="button" id="leslie">
                Add
            </button>
        </div>

        <div id="members">
            <h5>Team Members</h5>
            <hr />

        </div>
        <script>

            $("#john").click(function() {
                $("#members").append("John Howard");
            });

            $("#leslie").click(function() {
                $("#members").append("<br/>Leslie Holmes");
            });

            $("#Map").on('mouseenter', function(e) {

                $("#content").stop().show();
                //$("#content").css("visibility", "show");
                $("#content").offset({
                    left : e.pageX,
                    top : e.pageY
                });
                var alt_script = $("area").attr("alt");
                $("#content h4").html(alt_script);
            });

            $("#content").on('mouseenter', function(e) {

                $("#content").stop().show();
                //$("#content").css("visibility", "show");

            });

            $("#Map").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
                $("#content").stop().hide();
            });

            $("#content").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
                $("#content").stop().hide();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the image in the code: http://imgur.com/eJK42SZ

Like I have a "Content" div for one image map area & I would like to use a different div for another area, say named "Content1". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

## Update Answer

You mean something like this, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Pgqh3/3/

I created 2 divs for Script and Workbook, mouser hover and see.

If you want to overlap with each other, use `z-index`

```
<div id="map">
    <div id="content1">Script</div>
    <div id="content2">Workbook</div>
</div>

#map {
    float:left;
    width:946px;
    height:653px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/eJK42SZ.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}
#content1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:110px;
    left:170px;
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#dfdfdf;
    border:1px solid #000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#content1:hover {
    background:red;
}
#content2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:240px;
    left:170px;
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#dfdfdf;
    border:1px solid #000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#content2:hover {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: So is it possible to use divs in images?

Comment: yes, anything, insert image or set background image by css. as you wish.

Comment: Set your main image as div's background image first. Then, you can add DIVs on that.

Comment: Let me try this solution now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a different class for each area in the map and then use that class in jQuery when you attach mouseenter and mouseleave methods, so they will activate only on one exact area. And I suppose you better to use .hover function :)